# Does a closed form solution exist for $\beta$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am having trouble trying to solve this equation for an unknown matrix $\beta$.$$K = \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i \sum_{j=1}^p (A_j + A_j^T)\beta(C_j + C_j^T)$$ where $\tau_i$ is a scalar constant, and $A_j$, $C_j$, K are matrices of constants.

Comment: How about e.g. $\beta=0$ as the unique scalar solution when $\sum\tau_i(A_j+A_j^T)(C_j+C_j^T)\neq 0$?

Comment: ah, I updated the problem. Took too much out of the equation when posting it. Updated the question.

Comment: I see a few notational simplifications. First, you only use the index $i$ for the scalar constants $\tau_i$. So at present the sum over $i$ just factors out and you might as well define $K':=K/\sum_i^n \tau_i$. Second, the only relevant properties for the matrices $A_j+A_j^T$ and $C_j+C_j^T$ are that they're symmetric matrices. So we might as well relabel these as $A'_j,C'_j$. With this we have $K'=\sum_{j=1}^p A'_j \beta C'_j$ where $A'_j,C_j'$ are symmetric for all $j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that this can be solved using only typical matrix operations (e.g. additions multiplications and transposes). However, it can be solved using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

**Notation:** Let $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ denote the (column-major) vectorization of $A$. Let $\otimes$ denote the Kronecker product. Denote $B_j = A_j + A_j^T$, $D_j = C_j + C_j^T$; note that these matrices are symmetric.

We can vectorize both sides of the equation and simplify as follows.
$$
K = \sum_i \tau_i \sum_j B_j \beta D_j\\
\operatorname{vec}(K) = \operatorname{vec}\left[\sum_i \tau_i \sum_j B_j \beta D_j \right]\\
\operatorname{vec}(K) = \sum_i \tau_i \sum_j \operatorname{vec}(B_j \beta D_j)\\
\operatorname{vec}(K) = \sum_i \tau_i \sum_j (D_j \otimes B_j)\operatorname{vec}(\beta).
$$
We can solve this for $\operatorname{vec}(\beta)$ to find that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(\beta) = \left[\sum_i \tau_i \sum_j (D_j \otimes B_j)\right]^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(K) = 
\frac{\left[\sum_j (D_j \otimes B_j)\right]^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(K)}{\sum_i \tau_i }.
$$
Obtain $\beta$ by "unvectorizing" $\operatorname{vec}(\beta)$.